# Receiving Apache php error notices despite having 'if(isset) in use

Tags: php, apache

My Apache log is full of notices like the following:

> [Sun Aug 11 09:11:36 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: view in /var/www/components/com_content/router.php on line 59

Here's the referenced bit of code:

```
    if (($menuItem instanceof stdClass) && $menuItem->query['view'] == $query['view'] && isset($query['id']) && $menuItem->query['id'] == (int) $query['id'])ug

    {       
            unset($query['view']);

            if (isset($query['catid']))
            {       
                    unset($query['catid']);
            }

            if (isset($query['layout']))
            {       
                    unset($query['layout']);
            }

            unset($query['id']);

            return $segments;
    }
```

From what I've read, the isset is the most common solution for this, but it's not making a difference.  Anyone else come across a solution?

Comment: The message says "undefined index: view". Do you think `isset` checking for the index "id" would help with this?

Comment: in the first line `$query['view']` is referenced without `isset()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `isset()` check to right after the `stdClass` check.

In other words, change

```
($menuItem instanceof stdClass) && $menuItem->query['view'] == $query['view'] && isset($query['id']) && $menuItem->query['id'] == (int) $query['id'])
```

to

```
($menuItem instanceof stdClass) && isset($query['id']) && $menuItem->query['view'] == $query['view'] && $menuItem->query['id'] == (int) $query['id'])
```

Comment: Looks like that was the issue.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to a `view` index in both `$menuItem->query`and `$query` and PHP complains about `Undefined index: view`, so I assume one or both of those variables doesn't have a `view`index.